# How do Lambba works in Java when using Thread and Runnable?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, concurrency

My IDE(IntelliJ) suggest to replace this code:

```
private void countIterations() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long startTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long endTimestamp = startTimestamp + ITERATIONS_COUNTER_DURATION_SEC * 1000;

            int iterationsCount = 0;
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTimestamp) {
                iterationsCount++;
            }

            Log.d(
                    "Exercise1",
                    "iterations in " + ITERATIONS_COUNTER_DURATION_SEC + "seconds: " + iterationsCount
            );
        }
    }).start();

}
```

With this:

```
private void countIterations() {
    new Thread(() -> {
        long startTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long endTimestamp = startTimestamp + ITERATIONS_COUNTER_DURATION_SEC * 1000;

        int iterationsCount = 0;
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTimestamp) {
            iterationsCount++;
        }

        Log.d(
                "Exercise1",
                "iterations in " + ITERATIONS_COUNTER_DURATION_SEC + "seconds: " + iterationsCount
        );
    }).start();

}
```

My questions is how does it know that it's a Runnable? Both Thread and Runnable have the run method.

Comment: It knows it through type inference. `new Thread(Runnable)` expects... well... a `Runnable`, thus the lambda must be an implementation of `Runnable`.

Comment: In addition to above. Calling any of `new Thread(new Thread())` or pass `new Runnable` or lambda, will resolve the Thread constructor to (runnable), but you cannot pass new Thread as lambda, because it's a class. the lambda expression is a shorthand for passing only a functional interfaces.

Comment: In addition to the previous, correct, comments, I would add that this is known as target typing i.e., inferring the type based on the target the lambda is to be assigned or passed to.

Comment: In addition to _all_ the previous comments, in modern Java there's rarely a good reason to use `new Thread`; you should be using an `Executor` instead.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- That depends on what the `run()` method does.  In this case, you probably are right because the `run()` method appears to do one single thing and then exit. But for a long-running thread, then it might make more sense to call an appropriate [`ThreadFactory` object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how does it know that it's a `Runnable?`

First of all, let's make sure we know what "a Runnable" means. Experienced Java programmers say that without thinking about it too deeply, but `Runnable` is not a class. It's an *interface*: It's a specification of one or more methods that some *actual* class is expected to have.  When we say "a Runnable," what we really mean is, "an instance of some class that `implements Runnable`."

So how does the compiler know that the lambda expression must create "a runnable?" That's easy. The compiler has seen the declaration of the `Thread` class, and the `Thread` class declaration explicitly says that the argument to the constructor must be a Runnable.

> Both `Thread` and `Runnable` have the `run()` method.

OK. `Thread implements Runnable`, but it would not make any sense to use a `Thread` instance there because the `Thread` class `run()` method does not do the things that you want your thread to do. The compiler *must* define a completely new class with a `run()` method that does all of the stuff that you put into the body of your lambda. There is no other class in the system that already does all of those things.

OK, so why does the new class not `extends Thread`? (or, `extends` any other existing class that `implements Runnable`?)

Simply because there's no reason for that.  The `Thread` constructor doesn't say that it wants a `Thread` argument. It says it wants a `Runnable` argument. It will be happy with *any* class that `implements Runnable`, and it will never do anything with the object except to call its `run()` method.

OK, but how does the compiler know to make the body of the lambda into a method named `run()`?

Because `Runnable` is an `@functional` interface that declares exactly one method. A `Runnable` object *must* have a `run()` method, and the interface does not specify any other method, so there isn't any other choice.